# Multiple Criteria for Boolean Indexing

Tags: python, filter, boolean

What's the best way to pass multiple criteria, either of which are valid, to an array and return a boolean index than can then be used as a filter? The available solutions follow an if, then framework, which is more than I need.

I understand that I can do the following:

```
In[1]: 
names = np.array(['Bob','Joe','Bob','Will'])
data = np.random.randn(4,4)
mask = (names=='Bob')|(names=='Will')
data[mask]

Out[1]: 
array([[-0.25883247, -0.06236544, -0.02296274,  1.36340923],
       [ 0.3907503 , -2.38917418, -0.49057852, -0.25427256],
       [ 0.02648891, -1.27278901, -0.31815915,  1.72876199]])
```

But what if I had 100 names to test instead of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the names in a list, and then use `np.in1d` to generate the `mask`:

```
mask = np.in1d(names, ['Bob', 'Will'])

mask
# array([ True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I had incorrectly assumed that this would also work for a pandas series while also retaining the index values of that series.  It doesn't, though.  Is there another solution that does?

Comment: If you have a pandas Series, the equivalent version is `isin` method. So `names.isin(['Bob', 'Will'])`.